# Postgers: No unique or exclusion constraint matching ON CONFLICT specification when using a primary key and a UNIQUE column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the schema

```
CREATE TABLE instagram_posts (
post_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
user_id int REFERENCES instagram_users ON DELETE RESTRICT,
link TEXT UNIQUE,
caption TEXT, 
num_likes int,
num_comments int,
exsits BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE);
```

And I would try to call the command:

```
INSERT INTO instagram_posts (link,num_likes,user_id) VALUES (%s,%s,(SELECT user_id from instagram_users WHERE user_account=%s)) ON CONFLICT (post_id, link) DO UPDATE SET num_likes=EXCLUDED.num_likes,user_id=EXCLUDED.user_id;
```

Which gives me an **Error: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification**

The query works if I only include post_id as a constraint or only include the link as a constraint (ie ON CONFLICT (post_id) or ON CONFLICT(link)) but not both. I cannot think of a reason why that is. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

For exactly the reason it tells you — you don't have a unique constraint on `(post_id, link)` to power the ON CONFLICT clause. You could create such a constraint, but that seems rather pointless when the two keys making up the composite key are already individually unique. Probably `ON CONFLICT (link)` is exactly what you want, but it's not completely clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Aren't both post_id and link unique already? Can you expand on what you mean by there is no unique constraint on (post_id, link)? I am trying to make it so that if insert violates either constraint it will update.

Comment: @MaxYuan what you're asking the DB for is the exact opposite of that. A unique constraint, or an on conflict cause, on multiple columns means that the *combination* of the columns must be unique, not the individual columns; i.e. the tuples `(a,1)`, `(a,2)`, and `(b,2)` would contain *no conflicts*.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes sense why what I had doesn't work now. Do you know of a straight forward way to check if either column has a conflict?

Comment: @MaxYuan not offhand, you may want to research that or ask it as a new question :)