# How can I fix t"here is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification" when I have specified it?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like the following (Fields have been redacted to the relavant parts):

```
create_table "codes", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.uuid "campaign_id", null: false
    t.citext "code", null: false
    t.citext "code_id"
    t.index ["campaign_id", "code"], name: "unique_campaign_code", unique: true
    t.index ["campaign_id", "code_id"], name: "unique_campaign_code_id", unique: true
  end
```

As you can see, I have the following indexes that are very important to my application.

```
 t.index ["campaign_id", "code"], name: "unique_campaign_code", unique: true
 t.index ["campaign_id", "code_id"], name: "unique_campaign_code_id", unique: true
```

What I'm trying to do is to get an insert into another table when I run into a `CONFLICT ON` duplicate error. However, I can't get past this small hurdle when I execute my sql statement (below).

```
 "
   INSERT INTO codes SELECT * FROM codes_temp ct 
     ON CONFLICT (campaign_id, code_id, code) 
   DO UPDATE SET updated_at = excluded.updated_at;
 ")
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following:

`ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification (PG::InvalidColumnReference)`

I've read some stack overflow questions on this topic but i can't seem to adjust the answers to what I need. This link here was the closest I can find

[Postgers: No unique or exclusion constraint matching ON CONFLICT specification when using a primary key and a UNIQUE column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61049712/postgers-no-unique-or-exclusion-constraint-matching-on-conflict-specification-w)

but it doesnt quite answer my question. I dont' know if the creation of the indexes are wrong or maybe I don't have it configured properly but I could use some help please. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try index name instead of columns after "on conflict"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have one matching unique constraint, not multiple overlapping unique constraints. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) explains how this "unique index inference" is done.

Add

```
t.index ["campaign_id", "code", "code_id"], name: "unique_campaign_code_code_id", unique: true
```

and your query will work.

Comment: Hey @SebDieBln thank you for the answer. I did get past the error but it did kind of change the way my app works, but knowing this will help me troubleshoot. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I myself once had to circumvent ON CONFLICT's shortcoming of only being able to check one constraint, even if a table has multiple.